# Does 東京 have a nickname?

Tags: words

New York is called the Big Apple, Seattle is the Emerald City. Does 東京 have a nickname?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tokyo ***does not*** have a nickname in the same sense that New York City has the nickname, the Big Apple.

Tokyo can occasionally be referred to by its old name 「江戸{えど}」 when that fits the speaker/writer's aesthetic purposes.  One would definitely need a native-level fluency to use it "correctly".  If used randomly, it would sound ludicrous at best.

It is not a common practice at all to give towns nicknames in Japanese culture, but as a rare exception, quite a few places (most notably 金沢{かなざわ}) are often referred to as 「小京都{しょうきょうと}」 ("Little Kyoto") mainly for tourism-related purposes.  It is a compliment in our culture to say that a town or area reminds one of Kyoto.

Back to Tokyo...

If the degree of recognition in the present time did not matter, Tokyo was called **the Big Mikan** for a short period of time a few decades ago.  But it was outside of the Japanese-speaking culture and it never took off even in the U.S. where the name was created.

https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=Big+Mikan